# predict interaction effect when raw data doesn´t cover the whole range of the interaction

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, prediction, generalized-additive-model

I'm trying to model one binary response (y) as a function of one continuous variable ("size"). I'm using a generalized additive mixed-effects model using bam (library mgcv) because I have a random effect (individual ID) and millions of data points.

I'm expecting a non-linear relationship between "y" and "size" which would also depend on the value of another variable, "shape", which is also continuous. My initial thought was to model y as a function of the interaction between "size" and "shape". However, my dataset doesn't cover the whole range of the interaction between "size" and "shape". I mean, when the "size" is small, then the "shape" metric tends to be small, but as "size" gets larger, then "shape" can take any value, from very small to very large. The Pearson correlation between "size" and "shape" is 0.65 and the VIF is 1.8.

If I model `y~te(size,shape)` and then predict in the whole range of "size" and "shape" in my dataset, then the predictions for the area where I have no data (small size and large shape) are unrealistic.

I have also tried to discretize "shape" (three levels) and the model `y~s(size,by=shape)`. If I make predictions in the whole range of "size" for each of the three levels, then I get the same problem as in the continuous interaction, because for the "small" level of "shape", the predictions when "size" is large are unrealistic (this is the region where there is no data).

Then I thought of two potential solutions, and I'd like to know which one is better (if any), or if there is an alternative.

1) Model `y~s(size,by=shape)`, but then predict using three different data.frames, one for each level of "shape" which includes only the range of size present for each level. So 1 model but 3 data frames for prediction.

2) Split the dataset in three: one for each level of "shape". And then model and predict separately `y~s(size)`. So 3 models and 3 data frames for prediction.